# Is there any risk to use .png filename for JPG format images on my website?

Tags: html, image, mime-types

I have a lot of pictures to be uploaded on my website `example.com/images/`

The files are in JPG format and their names are `1.jpg` or `55.jpg`.

However, I can't change the HTML due to some legacy reasons, so the images in my page have to be ending with a `.png` name in the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag.

```
<img src="1.png" />
```

Is it possible to just directly change the filename extension from `jpg` to `png` without actually updating the image compression algorithm? Is there any risk for some browsers that might not be able to render the images correctly?

Comment: The image formats usually have an internal signature to identify them and are "extension neutral". So do PNG and JPEG. I would expect the browsers to follow this behavior. But what does it cost you to give it a try ?

Comment: Sure, I can give it a try but I can't test all browsers and cases.

Comment: What do you call "cases" ? It seems that many browsers share the same rendering engine.